# Change individual content styling when respective links are clicked

Tags: jquery, anchor, highlight

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this, but I want to create a list of links that scroll to various anchors on the same page, each with different bits of information. However, when the link is  clicked, I would like the appropriate content to be highlighted in some way so that it is obvious what to look at.

```
<a href="1">LINK1</a>
<a href="2">LINK2</a>
<a href="3">LINK3</a>
<a href="4">LINK4</a>
<a href="5">LINK5</a>

<a name="1">INFORMATION1</a>
<a name="2">INFORMATION2</a>
<a name="3">INFORMATION3</a>
<a name="4">INFORMATION4</a>
<a name="5">INFORMATION5</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the simplest level, you just use the `:target` selector in your CSS.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ya4xM/1/***

1. Use `id` instead of name.
2. Use hash labels.
3. Ideally don't use anchors for targets. Use any element.

*HTML*:

```
<a href="#l1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#l2">Link 2</a>
...
<p id="l1">...</p>
<p id="l2">...</p>
```

*CSS*:

```
p:target {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Once you click another link, the style would automatically get reset as the target changes. You can also use CSS to have interesting effects like a yellow fade.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ya4xM/3/***

Comment: is there a way to deactivate it once another link is clicked? ..and highlight the next element

Comment: It will automatically deactivate once another link is clicked. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ya4xM/3/

Comment: I'm having a really strange issue! When you click any link for the first time, the element is missed. Then when you click a second time it corrects to the right position. See here lk-consultants.co.uk/services.html I noticed the problem went away when I removed 'clear:both' from my css. But I need that!

Comment: Can't open the link as I am on mobile. I should be able to see that tomorrow as I have retired for the day.

Comment: @user3279760: I just checked your site. It seems to be working just fine. No problems at all. And yes, it looks sleek.